# Display CLI app on a terminal screen, starting it from another (ssh)

Tags: ssh, terminal, raspberry-pi, command-line-interface

i've a command line interface based app i would like to display on the hdmi displayed terminal screen, starting it from an ssh connected terminal or indicating it from the systemd service definition.
How can I?

Let's say this is my app for example, how can i launch it on a different terminal?

```
var blessed = require('blessed');

var screen = blessed.screen({
  smartCSR: true
});


var message = blessed.text({
  parent: screen,
  top: 'center',
  left: 'center',

});

setInterval(()=>{
  message.setContent(new Date().toUTCString())
  screen.render();
}, 1000)

screen.key(['escape', 'q', 'C-c'], function (ch, key) {
  return process.exit(0);
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well was pretty easy actually, assuming you are targeting tty1

```
node app > /dev/tty1 &
```